# UPPER() doesn't work with cyrillic symbols in PostgreSQL 8.2 database

Tags: sql, postgresql, encoding

I have PostgreSQL 8.2 running on Ubuntu server, database encoding is UTF8. Everything is fine, except one thing: I cannot use `upper()` function in sql queries for cyrillic symbols. Well, I can use it, but the result of the function will still be in lowercase.

How could this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be fixed by **upgrading** your version of PostgreSQL, preferably to the current version 9.1. PostgreSQL 8.2 has been [released in 2006 and reached end of life](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Release_Support_Policy) recently.

There have been a large number of improvements for locales since then. As far as I can see, it works for me in version 9.0 (on Debian Squeeze):

```
SELECT upper('ѓғг̡г̨һһ̨дђеёӗ');
```

Result:

```
ЃҒГ̡Г̨ҺҺ̨ДЂЕЁӖ
```

Note: I use `UTF8` as `server_encoding`, `UNICODE` as `client_encoding` and `*.UTF-8` (`de_AT.UTF-8` to be precise) for all locale settings (`lc_*`). Other encodings or locales may have specific problems. You might want to show us the output of this query:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_settings WHERE name ~~ '%encod%' OR name ~~ 'lc%'
```

---

#### Edit after feedback in comments:

If "nothing" is set, that means the pseudo-locale `C` (aka `Posix`) is set. `C` is agnostic to any locale settings, which allows for faster sort operations. It also means that your system has no idea, what the upper case equivalent of a cyrillic letter is supposed to be.

Be sure to read the chapter [Locale Support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/locale.html) in the manual. (Links to version 8.2, [current version here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/locale.html).)

However, `LC_CTYPE` can only be set at db cluster creation time. In newer versions you can base a new database off `template0` and specify different locale and encoding settings, but not in version 8.2.

So, I come back to my initial advise: best course of action would be to install a more recent version of PostgreSQL. And remember to set up your desired locale when setting up the new db cluster.

[PostgreSQL 9.1 is available for Debian Squeeze](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze-backports/postgresql-9.1). So, there should be something for Ubuntu, too.

Comment: well, 8.2 is the latest in the ubuntu server repository, that's why i have it installed

Comment: my lc_ settings for server are not even defined o_O

Comment: @DataGreed: That's the answer to your problem right there. I added some more info to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It might be something about the [character set](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/multibyte.html).

---

To avoid this problem you can do the `upper function` yourself.

As seen [here](http://www.ascii-codes.com/cp855.html) that should be done by adding one to the ascii chacacter value.

> 128   80  Cyrillic lower case dje
>
> 129   81  Cyrillic upper case DJE

*Or* you could have a conversion table and compare the value, etc.

Comment: no-no, i have another server where this function works great, but unfortunately i have no access to the server now, so i cannot check what's different in the config

Answer (score 0):

The collation rules which are part of the [locale](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/locale.html#AEN23691) are responsible for determining how to convert an lower-case character to upper-case one and vice versa. Check yours!